# how do I populate the Favorites channel group in mythtv?

Tags: mythtv

I have just completed the installation of mythTV inn Ubuntu 18.04. It works.  However, I want to set up a second channel group using the predefined Favorites group.  When I access this via the front-end, things seem to work, but my channels are not saved.  This seems like a permissions issue, but I'm not sure.  Can anybody advise what I have to do? Thanks!

Comment: Did you use apt-get to install it, or build from source? Did you follow the steps as shown at https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Installing_MythTV_on_Ubuntu , and if so, please recap them, step by step, in the way you did them.  Did you set up channel groups in MythTv using its Frontend Channel Editor, or in MythWeb ? Please click on the grey edit link above-left and add the results to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I found that using the arrow keys to navigate mythfrontend solved it. After selecting the channels, use the left arrow key to exit editor. Then either ESC or left arrow will prompt for saving changes. If I used ESC to exit channel selection, it would prompt for save but did not. 18.04 with v29.1.